# Microsoft Azure Web Chat Bot connection to Facebook Channel is not updating

Tags: facebook, azure, web, bots, channel

I have connected an Azure Web Bot to a facebook channel. The connection was working, and the bot responded as expected. But when I update my Bot Facebook still uses the old Version. I've tested in "Test in Web Chat" and that is using the new Version. Only Facebook still uses the old one. I'm sure I'm only missing some sort of a republish, but I've no idee where to search for that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found this solution:

The Bot stays in a state where the Communication was started. So to get it with the new Bot you have to post a message
" /deleteprofile" to your bot (be aware of the leading space)

Then the channel communicates to the new bot version.